# RuntimeError: cd /var/www/discourse && su discourse -c ‘bundle exec rake assets:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-ocean, discourse

I've got a failure by bootstrapping a Discourse:
RuntimeError: cd /var/www/discourse && su discourse -c 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' failed with return #.

```
   171:signal-handler (1464162030) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
        2016-05-25 07:40:30 UTC [42-2] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
        2016-05-25 07:40:30 UTC [42-3] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
        2016-05-25 07:40:30 UTC [49-2] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
        2016-05-25 07:40:30 UTC [46-1] LOG:  shutting down
        2016-05-25 07:40:30 UTC [46-2] LOG:  database system is shut down
        171:M 25 May 07:40:30.426 # User requested shutdown...
        171:M 25 May 07:40:30.427 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
        171:M 25 May 07:40:30.444 * DB saved on disk
        171:M 25 May 07:40:30.445 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...


        FAILED
        --------------------
        RuntimeError: cd /var/www/discourse && su discourse -c 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' failed with return #<Process::Status: pid 289 exit 137>
        Location of failure: /pups/lib/pups/exec_command.rb:105:in `spawn'
        exec failed with the params {"cd"=>"$home", "hook"=>"bundle_exec", "cmd"=>["su discourse -c 'bundle install --deployment --verbose --without test --without development'", "su discourse -c 'bundle exec rake db:migrate'", "su discourse -c 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile'"]}
        b61c02fe6e3dbd6ab382d23592fab25bdcba02fc7666f20cd9874c521bf2e537
        ** FAILED TO BOOTSTRAP ** please scroll up and look for earlier error messages, there may be more than one
        root@ubuntu-512mb-nyc2-01:/var/discourse#
```

Also I've tried rebuilt and destroy that, but it isn't helping unfortunately.

```
root@ubuntu-512mb-nyc2-01:~# sudo ./launcher rebuild app
sudo: ./launcher: command not found
root@ubuntu-512mb-nyc2-01:~# cd /var/discourse
root@ubuntu-512mb-nyc2-01:/var/discourse# sudo ./launcher rebuild app
Ensuring launcher is up to date
Fetching origin
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
From https://github.com/discourse/discourse_docker
   5819e89..8c92508  master     -> origin/master
Updating Launcher
Updating 5819e89..8c92508
Fast-forward
 templates/postgres.template.yml | 1 -
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
Usage: launcher COMMAND CONFIG [--skip-prereqs] [--docker-args STRING]
Commands:
    start:      Start/initialize a container
    stop:       Stop a running container
    restart:    Restart a container
    destroy:    Stop and remove a container
    enter:      Use nsenter to get a shell into a container
    logs:       View the Docker logs for a container
    bootstrap:  Bootstrap a container for the config based on a template
    rebuild:    Rebuild a container (destroy old, bootstrap, start new)
    cleanup:    Remove all containers that have stopped for > 24 hours

Options:
    --skip-prereqs             Don't check launcher prerequisites
    --docker-args              Extra arguments to pass when running docker

    root@ubuntu-512mb-nyc2-01:/var/discourse# sudo ./launcher start app

    + /usr/bin/docker run -d --restart=always -e LANG=en_US.UTF-8 -e RAILS_ENV=production -e UNICORN_WORKERS=3 -e UNICORN_SIDEKIQS=1 -e RUBY_GLOBAL_METHOD_CACHE_SIZE=131072 -e DISCOURSE_DB_SOCKET=/var/run/postgresql -e DISCOURSE_DB_HOST= -e DISCOURSE_DB_PORT= -e DISCOURSE_HOSTNAME=cleaneone.com -e DISCOURSE_DEVELOPER_EMAILS=tamerlanium@gmail.com -e DISCOURSE_SMTP_ADDRESS=smtp.gmail.com -h ubuntu-512mb-nyc2-01-app -e DOCKER_HOST_IP=172.17.0.1 --name app -t -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /var/discourse/shared/standalone:/shared -v /var/discourse/shared/standalone/log/var-log:/var/log --mac-address 02:0f:a9:e5:74:fb local_discourse/app /sbin/boot
    Unable to find image 'local_discourse/app:latest' locally
    Pulling repository docker.io/local_discourse/app
    /usr/bin/docker: Error: image local_discourse/app not found.
    See '/usr/bin/docker run --help'.

root@ubuntu-512mb-nyc2-01:/var/discourse# sudo ./launcher destroy app
+ /usr/bin/docker stop -t 10 app
Error response from daemon: No such container: app
app was not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I write down some tips, because i can't know if you're updating discourse or installing it for the first time:

Before launching rebuild, be sure that launcher and everything is updated:

```
cd /var/discourse
git pull
./launcher rebuild app
```

When you have a "Failed to bootstrap" error you can try to start the container yourself:

```
./launcher start app
```

If this doesn't take your forum back online, check that docker is updated:

```
docker --version
```

If it's not:

```
apt-get update; apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I fixed it by the using SWAP for a $5 Droplet on the DigitalOcean :)